# Migration from Teradata to MYSQL over partition by

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, teradata

**Working SQLs in Teradata**

```
select  row_number() over (partition by job_name, parent_job_name order by elapsed_sec) as rowno from  schema.xyz

select min(elapsed_sec) over (partition by job_name, parent_job_name order by elapsed_sec rows between 1 following and 1 following) - elapsed_sec as diff from schema.xyz
```

**Not Working SQLs in MYSQL**

```
select  row_number() over (partition by job_name, parent_job_name order by elapsed_sec) as rowno from  schema.xyz

select min(elapsed_sec) over (partition by job_name, parent_job_name order by elapsed_sec rows between 1 following and 1 following) - elapsed_sec as diff from schema.xyz
```

Getting error as row_number doesn't exist. Kindly help in conversion.

Comment: your query works in mysql 8 , so which version are you using

Comment: mysql workbench 8.0.20

Comment: that is the gui not the database itself.but after changing schema to an Database that actually exists, that query runs in mysql 8.0.20

Comment: ok got it.. Version 5.6.10 MYSQL Community Server(GPL)

Comment: there your query doesn't work, because window functions only where itroduced in version 8, look for replacement and workarounds

Comment: Why are you migrating to MYSQL 5.6?

Comment: That MYSQL instance is running on AWS RDS. Can anyone suggest resolution? I can't suggest client to upgrade version @lennart

Comment: As far as I know we can use session variable. But how it works with partition by that I am not sure

Comment: You can find examples of how to mimic window functions here http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/en/book_equivalents_for_analytic_functions.html

Comment: @lennart Can you take a look and suggest if possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62633292/conversion-teradata-to-mysql-aurora-without-analytical-function